# Simple math not displaying as expected?

Tags: java, math

Why is not "int total = (mark/overall) * 100;" working? When I entered 25 and 50 which should be 50% after it calculates 25/50 * 100. But it displayed 0% instead which is very strange. Any suggestions??

```
    public class MarksCalculator {
        private static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        public static void main (String[]args) {

            int mark = 0, overall = 0;

            //System.out.print("Hello Deepo!  To calculate the marks enter value (percantage) of the task: ");
            //int weight = kb.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter your marks for this Task/Assesment/Test: ");
            mark = kb.nextInt();

            System.out.print("What was this mark out of: ");
            overall = kb.nextInt();

            int total = (mark/overall) * 100;

            System.out.println("You have scored " + total + "% with this assesment.");
}
}
```

Comment: Because 25/50 is 0 in `int` calculations. Cast one side to double (the other will be implicitly cast).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid floating points (but why?), you can also reorder the factors:

```
int total = 100 * mark / overall;
```

Comment: It works but that is weird. Why wouldn't mark/overall * 100 working if you have any good reason?

Comment: @Shuvo0o Because `mark/overall` will be evaluated first to 0, so multiplying it with 100 will be... 0.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast in double :

```
double total = ((double)mark/overall) * 100;
```

From [Chapter 15](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17) :

> If the promoted type is int or long, then integer arithmetic is
>   performed.

Comment: Where is "integer arithmetic" exactly defined in the JLS?

Comment: @ingyhere http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17 (See 15.17.2)

Comment: Yes, I saw that. It states, "If the promoted type is int or long, then integer arithmetic is performed." However, it does not provide a reference or explicit definition for 'integer arithmetic', or I cannot find it. I think we know what it is, but I am surprised the JLS does not provide a reference to Knuth or something.